# python pandas Data frame column has string value looks like list of dictionaries?

Tags: string, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe column that has string values in it (edited) 
type of dataframe column is string BUT (edited) 
its values look like list of dictionaries (edited) 
how can i extract some key value from that string?
This STRING value looks like List of dictionaries.

How can I extract value of `name` key when key 'job' has a value as 'Director?

```
[{
        'credit_id': '549e9edcc3a3682f2300824b',
        'department': 'Camera',
        'gender': 2,
        'id': 473,
        'job': 'Additional Photography',
        'name': 'Brian Tufano',
        'profile_path': None
    }, {
        'credit_id': '52fe4214c3a36847f8002595',
        'department': 'Directing',
        'gender': 2,
        'id': 578,
        'job': 'Director',
        'name': 'Ridley Scott',
        'profile_path': '/oTAL0z0vsjipCruxXUsDUIieuhk.jpg'
    }, {
        'credit_id': '52fe4214c3a36847f800259b',
        'department': 'Production',
        'gender': 2,
        'id': 581,
        'job': 'Producer',
        'name': 'Michael Deeley',
        'profile_path': None
    }, {
        'credit_id': '52fe4214c3a36847f800263f',
        'department': 'Writing',
        'gender': 2,
        'id': 584,
        'job': 'Novel',
        'name': 'Philip K. Dick',
        'profile_path': '/jDOKJN8SQ17QsJ7omv4yBNZi7XY.jpg'
    }, {
        'credit_id': '549e9f85c3a3685542004c7b',
        'department': 'Crew',
        'gender': 2,
        'id': 584,
        'job': 'Thanks',
        'name': 'Philip K. Dick',
        'profile_path': '/jDOKJN8SQ17QsJ7omv4yBNZi7XY.jpg'
    }, {
        'credit_id': '52fe4214c3a36847f800261b',
        'department': 'Writing',
        'gender': 2,
        'id': 583,
        'job': 'Screenplay',
        'name': 'Hampton Fancher',
        'profile_path': '/lrGecnLhzjzgwjKHvrmYtRAqOsP.jpg'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by converting your list into pandas dataframe:
[pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame(yourList)    
df['name'][df['job']=="Director"] # you will get a series of all the names matching your condition.
```

Or one more way is using .loc[]

```
df.loc[df["job"]=="Director",["name"]] # You will get a dataframe with name column having all the names matching the condition.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame(LIST)
Name=df['name'][df['job']=="Director"]
print('Name =',Name)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not only provide code - try to expain what it does. You should also use a multiline codebox (three backticks).

Comment: Expanding on @finnmglas's comment, code-only answers may help the OP, but they aren't usually helpful to people who come by later with similar questions.